# Where did I go wrong? Show $P\{S_n≥x\}=P\{S_n≤-x\}$ if $X_i$ and $-X_i$ have the same distribution

Tags: probability

The question is

> Let $\{X_i,1≤i≤n\}$ be independent discrete RVs. Suppose $X_i$ and $-X_i$ have the same distributions, show that for all $x$ we have $P\{S_n≥x\}=P\{S_n≤-x\}$ where $S_n=∑_{i=1}^nX_i$.

**My attempt**:
$Let X=(X_1,X_2,…,X_n)$ and $f(x)$ be the joint mass function of $X$. When ${X_i}$ are independent, then $f(x)=f(x_1 )f(x_2 )…f(x_n )$ where $f(x_i )$ is the mass function of $X_i$. Let $Ω_i=\{x∈\Bbb{R}:f(x_i )≠0\}$, and we have

> $\begin{gathered}
> P\left\{ {{S_n} \geqslant k} \right\} = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_n} \in {{{\Omega }}_n}} \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_{n - 1}} \in {{{\Omega }}_{n - 1}}}  \ldots \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_2} \in {{{\Omega }}_2}} \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( x \right) \hfill \\
>  = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_n} \in {{{\Omega }}_n}} \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_{n - 1}} \in {{{\Omega }}_{n - 1}}}  \ldots \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_2} \in {{{\Omega }}_2}} \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right)f\left( {{x_2}} \right) \ldots f\left( {{x_n}} \right) \hfill \\
>    = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_n} \in {{{\Omega }}_n}} f\left( {{x_n}} \right)\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_{n - 1}} \in {{{\Omega }}_{n - 1}}} f\left( {{x_{n - 1}}} \right) \ldots \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_2} \in {{{\Omega }}_2}} f\left( {{x_2}} \right)\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right) \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered} $

Similarly,

> $P\left\{ {{S_n} \leqslant  - k} \right\} = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_n} \in {{{\Omega }}_n}} f\left( {{x_n}} \right)\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_{n - 1}} \in {{{\Omega }}_{n - 1}}} f\left( {{x_{n - 1}}} \right) \ldots \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_2} \in {{{\Omega }}_2}} f\left( {{x_2}} \right)\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \leqslant  - k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right)$

Then I got stuck, because in order for the two series to be equal, we need to show

> $\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \leqslant  - k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right) = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right)$ ......(*)

The conditions we have is "$X_i$" and $-X_i$ has the same distribution" and thus $P\left\{ {{X_i} \leqslant x} \right\} = P\left\{ {{X_i} \geqslant  - x} \right\}$, from which we can only get $\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \leqslant  - k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right) = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k + \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right)$, which is different from (*).

I think the above approach should work, but where did I go wrong? Or is there any other way to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Here is an idea. If we assume the question is true, then $P\{ {X_1} + {X_2} + ... + {X_n} \geqslant k\}  = P\{ {X_1} - {X_2} - ... - {X_n} \geqslant k\} $, so $\mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \leqslant  - k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right) = \mathop \sum \limits_{{x_1} \in \left\{ {x \in {{{\Omega }}_1}:x \geqslant k - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 2}^n {x_i}} \right\}} f\left( {{x_1}} \right)$ holds with that assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potentially helpful shift in perspective: define $S_n'=\sum (-X_i)$. Both $S_n$ and $S_n'$ can be completely described in terms of identical joint distributions of independent variables, so they must have the same distribution. That is, for any $k$:
$$
P(S_n \geq x)=P(S_n' \geq x)
$$

---

The point here is that given the distributions of the variables $X_i$, we can completely describe the distribution of $S_n$.  So, in particular, let $\Omega_k \subset \Omega$ be the set of outcomes $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in which $\sum_{i}x_i \geq k$.  Then, we have
$$
P(S_n \geq k) = 
\sum_{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Omega_k} P(X_1 = x_1)P(X_2 = x_2)\cdots P(X_n = x_n)
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
P(S_n' \geq k) = 
\sum_{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Omega_k} P(-X_1 = x_1)P(-X_2 = x_2)\cdots P(-X_n = x_n)
$$
Because the $X_i$ and $-X_i$ are identically distributed, the outcome of these sums must be identical.  The desired conclusion follows.

It is noteworthy that independence is an essential assumption here; if the $X_i$ are not independent, then we can't deduce the  distribution of $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But since $S'_n=-S_n$, then isn' the claim "$S_n$ and $S'_n$ can be completely described in terms of identical joint distributions of independent variables, so they must have the same distribution" basically what the question asks us to prove? Can you provide some more detail of your hint? Thank you!

Comment: @Tony see my latest element.  It may seem like I said nothing at all before, but in fact I said just enough.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. That's a much easier way to do the problem!

Comment: (my latest edit, not element).  Were you able to find a counterexample for the second part?

Comment: Yes. I have found a counterexample. Thank you so much!